# How to add class to angular component in storybook?

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I defined a component "test-component-wrapper" with viewencapsulation setted to none. Its template has only an

```
<ng-content></ng-content>>
```

I defined also a "test-component-item" with this template

```
<div>Some text</div>
```

In storybook I tried to create a story with this template

```
<test-component-wrapper>
 <test-component-item class="testClass">
 </test-component-item>
</test-component-wrapper>
```

But it doesn't work...dom is not rendered. If I add this story without class it works. I tried so to it directly in angular project and class is added. How can I solve?

Comment: Can you insert minimal reproducable example? I might have an idea but I would like to provide valid case for your situation.

Comment: yes. this is an example: https://angular-ivy-idtchu.stackblitz.io. I tried to integrate storybook in stackblitz but I couldn't...

Comment: It doesn't seem to be loading for me (never loads till the end). Is there any other source/live server?